# How many py script can I run on raspberry pi simultaniously?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I know that you can run multiple scripts by using different terminals, but there's got to be a limit. I can't just run a million of them on one little pi. So the real question... Is there a way I can check how demanding my script is. Thank you in advance!

pi zero w / python 3

Comment: each python session will be using different amounts of memory depending on what they are doing. If you use more memory than available through RAM and swap, your sessions will crash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring the obvious limitations due to memory and CPU consumption, if you're running a Linux-based OS on your Raspberry PI you can check the contents of `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`. From [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

```
/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max (since Linux 2.5.34)
          This file specifies the value at which PIDs wrap around (i.e.,
          the value in this file is one greater than the maximum PID).
          PIDs greater than this value are not allocated; thus, the
          value in this file also acts as a system-wide limit on the
          total number of processes and threads.  The default value for
          this file, 32768, results in the same range of PIDs as on ear‐
          lier kernels.  On 32-bit platforms, 32768 is the maximum value
          for pid_max.  On 64-bit systems, pid_max can be set to any
          value up to 2^22 (PID_MAX_LIMIT, approximately 4 million).
```

In other words: on most default configurations, Linux will be able to run a maximum of 32,768 processes (and threads, combined) at the same time. Note that you're sharing those PIDs with everything else that's running on the system, including parts of the OS itself.

So let's say you have 150 processes and threads running by default and your script uses a negligible amount of CPU and memory and only a single thread, then you can run at most 32,618 instances of your script at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicitly fixed limit. Just like your desktop or laptop computer, the limit depends on how many resources each running program takes. And just like your computer, the result of consuming too many resources can vary. It can result in the programs just running more slowly or in a complete crash.